# Rundeck 2.10: howto remote logging to syslog

Tags: syslog, rundeck

on premise we got a Rundeck 2.10 and it's configured logging to local file. I would like to configure it for logging on a remote syslog-ng.
I've managed to search infos on web but I've only found this page: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/logs.html#streaming-log-plugins that talks about the "availability" of a Streaming Log Writers but I cannot find this plugin anywhere.

Someone got a guide to achieve this result?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have a good example written in [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/tree/main/examples/example-groovy-log-plugins). And [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/developer/12-option-values-plugins.html#groovy-plugin-type) a good explanation about Rundeck groovy plugins.

You can create a groovy file and put on the libext directory as [any Rundeck plugin](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/plugins/installing.html#installing-plugins).